# How do I create a new file with a slightly modified name and will be in the same folder?

Tags: java, path, io, persistence

I am creating a file based on the another. So if the original is called doc.txt and is in myDocs I want to have it called docv2.txt and also saved in myDocs.
All I need is to define the new files path I can do the rest. Please help me determine what that path would be.

Comment: What happens when you base the new file off a file called docv2.txt? Just keep things like that in mind when you're designing these systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File originalFile = ...;
String name = originalFile.getName();
int lastIndexOfDot = name.lastIndexOf('.');
String newFileName = name.substring(0, lastIndexOfDot)
                     + "v2" 
                     + name.substring(lastIndexOfDot);
File newFile = new File(originalFile.getParentFile(), newFileName);
```

Of course, you might want to improve this code in case you want to support files without any dot in their name.

This is basic String and File manipulation. Check the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) of those two classes: that's how you'll learn how to use them.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes files don't have a '.' in their name and and this needs to work for any file

Answer (score 1):

Look at the String Class and use the to string classes substring method in conjunction with the file.getPath

Answer (score 1):

Use the String class for basic string manipulation